# Solution to export and import browser's full state

Tags: browser, export, copy-paste, deep-copy

I'm looking for complete solution to export full browser data from one computer, move this and import on another computer, and continue using that browser's session.
Main point is site mustn't see any changes (the same cookies, the same localstorage, the same site's form states).

It can be any solution: browser, program, script, extension, using a virtual machine.